# Bxslider, Custom Fields & Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, bxslider

How  can I achieve two things with the existing code below:

1. Remove the null values, as these are exporting bxslider items that have broken links
2. For some reason two versions of each image in the the pager are showing. Can anyone see why and how i stop these duplicates.

   ```
   <ul class="bxslider">
   <?php
   $images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , "images", true);
   $images = unserialize($images);

   // Read into array

   foreach($images as $image)
       {
       $ar[] = array(
           "order" => $image['order'],
           "img_id" => $image['image_id'],
           "desc" => $image["desc"]
       );
       }

   // Sort array by order

   asort($ar);

   // Output data for Galleria

   foreach($ar as $item)
       {
       $image_id = $item['img_id'];
       $media_med = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, "medium", false);
       $media_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, "full", false);
       echo "<li><img data-title='" . $item["desc"] . "' data-big='" . $media_full[0] . "' src='" . $media_med[0] . "'></li>";
       }

   ?>
   </ul>
   <div id="bx-pager">
   <?php
   $images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , "images", true);
   $images = unserialize($images);

   // Read into array

   foreach($images as $image)
       {
       $ar[] = array(
           "order" => $image['order'],
           "img_id" => $image['image_id'],
           "desc" => $image["desc"]
       );
       }

   // Sort array by order

   asort($ar);

   // Output data for Galleria

   foreach($ar as $item)
       {
       $image_id = $item['img_id'];
       $media_med = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, "medium", false);
       $media_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, "full", false);
       echo "<a href='' data-slide-index='0'>";
       echo "<img src='" . $media_med[0] . "'>";
       echo "</a>";
       }

   ?>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can run array_filter() on the $ar array to remove false/ empty values.

Next, you probably don't need this line

```
$media_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, "full", false);
```

You could comment it out and it won't have any effect on the page.

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't had any experince with array_filter - can you include an example within the ocntext of my code please?

Comment: Just before you sort the array.

        array_filter($ar);
        asort($ar);